# showing count per category in ever row of that category in a new column

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
g <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)
m <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 2, 1, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 7, 3, NA, 1)
df <- data.frame(g, m)
```

I would like to show the number of non NA values per category of g (1 to 6) which I counted by:

```
  > df %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(m)))
    # A tibble: 6 x 2
          g non_na_count
      <dbl>        <int>
    1    1.            1
    2    2.            3
    3    3.            2
    4    4.            1
    5    5.            2
    6    6.            3
```

now I would like to produce a new column, l,  that shows the number of NA values per category in every row such that the result would be:

```
   g  m l
1  1  1 1
2  1 NA 1
3  1 NA 1
4  1 NA 1
5  2  3 3
6  2 NA 3
7  2  2 3
8  2  1 3
9  3  3 2
10 3 NA 2
11 3  3 2
12 3 NA 2
13 4 NA 1
14 4  4 1
15 4 NA 1
16 4 NA 1
17 5 NA 2
18 5  2 2
19 5  1 2
20 5 NA 2
21 6  7 3
22 6  3 3
23 6 NA 3
24 6  1 3
```

anyone know how this can be done :)?

Answer (score 1):

We need `mutate` to create column

```
df %>% 
 group_by(g) %>% 
 mutate(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(m)))
```

Comment: @Judith Sorry, didn't understasnd the comment

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. What you need to do is collect the output of group by and add it back to the original df.

`df_notna <- df %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(m)))
total <- merge(df,df_notna,by="g")`

Look at other ways to merge here: https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html